# Using Firebase for hosting, Socket.io for backend and React for frontend in one project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, socket.io, firebase-hosting

I have a socket.io server for backend and a React app as my frontend, which are located in different project folders (If it makes a difference at all). Is there a way to publish them both into one project and make them work with each other using Firebase hosting?

I have read that some guy tried to do that and a Firebase employee said it's better to use Realtime Databases. The problem with those is asynchronous calls, which makes my project useless. Socket.io helps with keeping data in order and makes everything work as intended.

Is there a way to... refractor the code to make Firebase Functions work like a socket.io? Is it worth it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not possible with Firebase products, in the way that you describe.  Cloud Functions doesn't do any streaming of requests or responses.

As another Firebase employee, I also strongly suggest you take a look at Realtime Database, since it effectively can do streaming between two clients using its synchronization mechanism.

I have no idea what you mean by "the problem with those is asynchronous calls, which makes my project useless".  Asynchronous programming is very standard these days, and for JavaScript and web development, asynchronous programming has always been the norm.

Comment: Maybe it is my level of coding, but the problem was simple: two requests at the same time led to complete nonsense inside of app. Now I'm trying to hook it up with Heroku, but it's also tricky for me :/

Comment: If you want to write your own server using socket.io, consider self-hosting it on one of the many raw Node.js hosting providers out there. If you're having a problem making your code work with Firebase, post a question with the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).